# Do I need a "frameworkName.h" header in my swift framework?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

When I create a framework in Xcode it will generate a header file containing:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for CoreLatchBluetooth.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for CoreLatchBluetooth.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyFrameworkVersionString[];
```

I don't want it to import UIKit, so I'm changing it to Foundation. But do I need this header file at all? What is it for?

Comment: Update: I've deleted all my "frameworkName.h" headers a long time ago and nothing changed.